# Uber API : Book job via API

Tags: php, cordova, uber-api

can anyone confirm either way whether it's possible to book an Uber job via the API?

I see no mention of it in the docs, so I would assume it's not possible, but still, I'd quite like to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blog post quite clearly states that it's implemented, but not yet available to all.

http://blog.uber.com/api

> What about requesting a ride? Yes, we’ve implemented that endpoint as well, but because calling it immediately dispatches a real driver in the real world, we’re releasing it in a more controlled fashion, starting with a small set of partners. Stay tuned for more on that, and please let us know if you’re interested in being added to the whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

The ride request API is now launched. Please see https://devblog.uber.com/take-your-users-for-a-spin/ for more information.